# first and last days of user input month

Tags: javascript, date

How to get first day and last day of the month that user input in javascript.

Example:

```
userInputMonth = 01; //jan
```

How to get first day and last day of the user input month

Comment: Although a first-class duplicate, remember, that in JavaScript months are zero-based, i.e. 0: January through 11: December!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use momentjs:

```js
// Instantiate this with any moment valid date string you want
var foo = moment();
console.log(foo.endOf('month'))
console.log(foo.startOf('month'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```